# Smarty {php} in TPL gives blank page

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I am new at smarty and i am trying to put some php code into a TPL

Example:

```
{php}echo 'test';{/php}
```

But no i am getting a blank page. Is it possible to enable {php} and how?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) Enable error reporting by adding `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your PHP script. 2. Check your file permissions. 3) Check your server logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been deprecated. From the documentation:

"As of Smarty 3.1 the {php} tags are only available from SmartyBC."

Source: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

Comment: And to add to that: they're deprecated for the very good reason that they defeat the point of using Smarty in the first place. If you want to write your templates in PHP, don't bother with Smarty.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree.